# I need to develop a Leave letter form in wordpress where the name, address, should be editable

Tags: wordpress, forms

I need to develop a Leave letter form in wordpress where the from shown below should be editable content/fill in blanks and submit the form

Example letter
[This is the format i need to do in wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiQxU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can create it easily with WP Everest Form. Here is a reference [link](https://wpeverest.com/blog/create-a-leave-request-form-in-wordpress/). May be it is helpful for you.

Comment: No, i have already used but this cant design the letter form by this plugin

Comment: i think there is plugin for that as E2PDF where thi plugin will help in converting the form to pdf format and store in file storage
https://wordpress.org/plugins/e2pdf/